# Is it okay if you unfreeze my Speculative History Discussion?

Tags: support, chat

If not, can you at least explain why?

The reason it froze was because I couldn't think of any interesting topics to talk about until recently. This time, it's actually related to speculative history.

My chat room didn't seem terribly popular, though.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm not mistaken, you are talking about your chatroom. As the automated message says, chat rooms are  frozen by the system if there's no activity for a long time. In this case, the last message was back in January.

I have unfrozen the room now, but in the future, you can keep the room open indefinitely by sending a message once a week or so.

Comment: I think that a chatroom gets automatically frozen after two weeks of lack of activity.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos FYI, you & Semaphore are both correct, in different ways. Shog9's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304201/562482) from Dec. 8, 2017 (I don't believe anything has likely changed since then) states "**Inactive moderator freeze** The room will be frozen if it is a private room and no moderator has said anything in the past 7 days." and "**Inactivity freeze** The room will be frozen if it has been inactive for 14 days." Thus, the time before freezing is one week or two weeks, depending on various conditions, but I don't know which category the OP's chatroom falls into.